# Mysql Alter table with Instant algorithm

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I just read this MySQL 8 official docs for new features of online DDL operation, where new algorithms added INSTANT. but I am a little bit confused about its working. Can someone please help me to understand the below statement

> The benefit of the INSTANT algorithm is that  only metadata changes
> are made in the data dictionary.  There is no need to acquire metadata
> lock during SE changes and we  don’t touch the data of the table.

Comment: in short prior you have to rebuild teh hole Table , which on realy big tables take forever. and UNSTANT helps with that problem see https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-innodb-now-supports-instant-add-column/

Comment: Here my doubt is about line "INSTANT algorithm is that only metadata changes are made in the data dictionary." so how while doing meta data change , concurrent DML is allowed ? and how its different from INPLACE algorithm ?

Comment: I linked the article, so that you get the general idea bhind it and can ask specific questions that are not covered. the examples are comprehenisive and you can try ot on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The manual goes into a lot of gory details; you can mostly ignore them.  In general, if you do not provide an "algorithm", the `ALTER` will pick the fastest way.  If you specify `INSTANT`, but that algorithm is not possible for what you want to change, it will spit at you.  (No harm done.)

At one extreme (the `COPY` end):  Changing the `PRIMARY KEY` (on InnoDB) requires rebuilding the entire table, reordering the data, and rebuilding all the indexes (because the PK is part of every secondary index).

At the other extreme (the `INSTANT` end):  Adding an option to the end of an `ENUM` list does not require touching the data at all.